# Contenteditable div not pasting images correctly

Tags: javascript, html

I have a `div` defined like so:

```
<div id="textarea" contenteditable="true">
  
</div>
```

[I set up a Codepen here.](https://codepen.io/skeithtan/pen/LYdmRPP) And when I try to copy an image from my email app and paste it on the div, it appears like so in Chrome:
[image: An image showing the filename of the images instead of the images themselves]

It shows the filename of the images instead of the actual images the images themselves.

If I copy it from Gmail's web app and paste it into the div, it appears like so in Chrome:
[image: Random string instead of the photos]

It shows a random string of characters instead of the images.

How can I make it show the image itself?

Some images do show up as an image, but I don't know the conditions that make the images show or just the file name / random characters in this case above.

Comment: _"It shows a random string of characters instead of the images."_ - that would most likely be a Data URI then. But I couldn't tell you whether those _can_ be inserted as images, I guess that is up to how the specific browser decided to handle that.

Comment: @CBroe is right about browsers. Depends also a lot also on how the email was developed. Maybe the image src is base64 data... so don't count on it.

Comment: yeah thats base64. chrome and firefox does this. to change the size of the img, just do [this](https://codepen.io/deanvangreunen/pen/XWEqNeN)